# Java Multi-Threading Performance Improvement

Tags: java, multithreading, file, mq

my application is taking around 200 milliseconds to complete a task using single thread.we have listener attached to MQ which will pick up the message and process it.

when i am increasing the number of MDB threads to 5 the processing time it should take to process 5 message in the queue should be around 200 milliseconds but it is taking around 600 milliseconds .what can be the issue or any suggestion to improve it.

we have File I/O ,DB insert update operation involved in between the process.

Comment: Where is the code? What processor are you using (nof cores)? Without this information we will not be able to help you.

Comment: If what you suggest was true, you could simply create 1000 threads and have 1000 messages handled in 200ms. That's not the case, because you don't have 1000 cores allowing to execute all the threads in parallel, and because all the tasks access other shared resources: the memory, the disk, another synchronized object, etc. Lets' take the disk as an example: it can't write at 5 different locations at the same time. So each thread has to wait for the disk to be available.

Comment: it is an 8 core processor.

Comment: Why do you expect to achieve perfectly linear scaling with the number of threads?

Comment: not expecting perfectly linear ...but it should be close to that ..right?

Comment: Depends.  Is there disk/memory I/O being performed?  Network communications?  Overhead in queuing and dequeuing messages, spawning threads and coordinating the thread pool?  Synchronization at any point in the code?  Any use of a shared resource that can't necessarily service 5 requests concurrently?

Comment: Like @JBNizet said, there are other resources in the entire system that could be shared amongst threads. So threads still have to wait on each other for those shared resources.

Comment: Increasing number of threads doesn't help in all situations , u need to tune your application. Start with2 then increase number of threads and notice timings

Comment: so if I have suppose File I/O involved in between which is taking x time which is a shared resource so any other parallel thread will have to wait for that thread to complete...is my understating correct...is it possible to create multi thread for such shared resources?

Comment: @saurabhgoyal no, the threads will each get some time to access the disk, which will also add to the overall time (because switching between threads also takes some time). But in the end, it boils down to the laws of physics: if you write to a single platter of your disk, you use a single write head, which can only write at one place at a time, and must move every time the location changes. The bandwidth of the bus, used to transfer information to the disk, is also limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tasks would be only CPU limited, it might be near linear scaling up to numbers of CPUs (cores) in your system. However as you said you're using shared resources, and that is probably the reason of your issue. Try profiling your application to see what is actually happening there.

Comment: This is not true. You only get near linear scaling, if and only if the app is easily parallelizable, which is not always the case.

Comment: What is actually not true in my statement?

Comment: Not CPU limited does not mean automatically linear scaling. How about racing conditions, synchronization etc.

Comment: That is true when you use shared memory in your application. When you use messaging (like the asker mentioned) you dont have to bother that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sharing MQ connections to the queue manager or does each thread have its own connection to the queue manager?